# function recv_exit_status not work as expected

Tags: python, ssh

I need to send a command via ssh and I need to get feedback if the command had been done successfully.
I tried to write this:

```
#Creating the session on the remote machine
notebook_remote_command = "nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser --port={} &\n".format(port_remote)
channel = client.invoke_shell()
channel.send(notebook_remote_command)
status = channel.recv_exit_status()
if status == "-1":
    exit(0)
```

but the the function `recv_exit_status` doesn't return.

Comment: Yahav, maybe I'm wrong about it, but shouldn't you be reading before calling `recv_exit_status()`?

Comment: @סטנליגרונן What am I should be reading?

Comment: I guess you should read/recv the command feedback, before the channel closes.

Comment: @סטנליגרונן I tried to receive the exit status immediately after sending the command (I closed the channel only after this)

Comment: Just recv() on the channel until exit_status_ready()...

Comment: @סטנליגרונן For some reason exit_status_ready() always return False. Do you have any reason why is that?

Comment: I think I made a mistake: what I meant is to call a read() or similar function before calling recv_exit_status()... not exit_status_ready()  as I have previously written by mistake ... Nevertheless, if  exit_status_ready() is now used: You may use this to poll the process status if you don’t want to block in recv_exit_status. It returns true or false. I guess you just called it once and it returned false (not ready). If you continue polling and it still returns false, then maybe there is some other issue.

Comment: @סטנליגרונן What I did was to poll the process status (while loop exit_status_ready() == False), and it was endless loop

Comment: I see... That's probably why recv_exit_status() doesn't return :( But at least you can use exit_status_ready() combined with a timeout or a retry counter... Hence you won't get stuck like when you used recv_exit_status().

Comment: Did you manage to get some sort of reply from the communication peer (server), a feedback or acknowledge, etc after sending the command ?

Comment: @סטנליגרונן What do you mean by "reply"?

Comment: You said you're supposed to get feedback if the command has been executed successfully... So, I assumed the feedback would be some sort of reply / answer coming from the peer (server).

Comment: @סטנליגרונן Let's say I want to write a string to file (on the remote), and then I need to read the file from the base, I need to know when the writing to the file was ended before I can start reading the file. but, exit_status_ready() always return false from some reason

Comment: Googling for a while I see others are using Paramiko implementation of SSH and they are focusing on the `exec_command()` method. Not sure this info is of very much help for you, but I have no other idea for the moment...

Comment: @סטנליגרונן The pbolem with exec_command() is that it doesn't run the command via the shell, and to run jupyter notebook command I need to invoke the shell